# Login to Discord.js from React App w/ Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discord, discord.js, react-tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './components/User';
import Discord, { Message } from 'discord.js'
import background from './images/background.png';
import './App.css';


const App = () => {

  const Discord = require('discord.js');
  const client = new Discord.Client();

  client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ready');
  });

  client.login('token');

  return (
    <body>
      <div className="App">

        <h1 className="nino-header">Hamsterland</h1>
        <h2 className="nino-subheader">Rewrite's <s>Best</s> Worst Moments</h2>
        <img className="background-image" src={background}/>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}
```

The ready event never fires; the bot does not come online. I am new to React and TypeScript—am I supposed to place the Discord login code somewhere else? The Token is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

I never really used the Discord API, but in react you cant make requests in the body of the function. You do that in a `useEffect`, which will only run when dependencies are changed. In this case, just don't pass any dependency and it will only run once when the component mounts.

```
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react';
import User from './components/User';
import Discord, { Message } from 'discord.js'
import background from './images/background.png';
import './App.css';

// You already imported Discord above
// const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Discord.Client();


const App = () => {

  useEffect(() => {
  
    

    client.on('ready', () => {
      console.log('ready');
    });

    client.login('token');

  },[])


  return (
    <body>
      <div className="App">

        <h1 className="nino-header">Hamsterland</h1>
        <h2 className="nino-subheader">Rewrite's <s>Best</s> Worst Moments</h2>
        <img className="background-image" src={background}/>
      </div>
    </body>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did exactly that but still no luck.

Comment: I assuming you're passing the token correctly, right? Also, is your node version above 12? You can type `node -v` on the terminal to check that. Node >12 is required for Discord.

Comment: Yeah, token is correct for sure. And node version is 14+.